# Backup of S3 Bucket in another Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have Bucket in this bucket 400Gb data, I want the backup of this bucket in another bucket but when I am using cp or sync from console it will taking a long time to copy one bucket to another bucket.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to automatically replicate data between Amazon S3 buckets, you can use either:

- Cross-Region replication, or
- Same-Region replication

These capabilities will automatically copy objects from one Amazon S3 bucket to another.

See: [Replication - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html)

If, on the other hand, you simply wish to copy this object occasionally, then using the AWS CLI `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` commands are the correct way to do so.

A 400GB file is rather large, therefore it will **take some time to copy**. If you are copying between regions, it will take even longer.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/trigger-cross-region-replication-of-pre-existing-objects-using-amazon-s3-inventory-amazon-emr-and-amazon-athena/ S3 supports crr/srr for existing objects as well.